# How can I convert '..' to '.'?

Tags: string, flutter

I have a text

```
String text = "abcd.."
```

and

```
String text2 = "abcd...."
```

I want to write a function and output "abcd."

like

```
function(String string){
//codes

return string // string must be "abcd." here
}
```

Comment: Please ask a pointed question. Do you just want to remove all the trailing dots till the last one, or it may contain other characters like $, %, & or some numer/alphabet because that changes stuff

Comment: So you want to replace all dots at the end of the string only with a single dot?

Comment: I want if there is a much dots convert them to a dot for example "abc.... Def.. "  to "abc. Def. "

Comment: > for example "abc.... Def.. " to "abc. Def. "  See now you're changing the rules from what I thought as well.  Is the rule "any sequence of dots in the string should be replaced with a single dot?"  Or are there other conditions to apply?

Answer (score 3):

If all occurrences of 2 or more dots should be replaced, you could use replaceAll with a pattern `\.{2,}` to match 2 or more dots and replace with a single dot.

```
String stripDots(String string){
    return string.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\.{2,}'), '.');
}

String text = "abc.... Def..";
print(stripDots(text));
```

Output

```
abc. Def.
```

[Dart demo](https://ideone.com/6vj8iB)